# Strange exception when using ConcurrentStack in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have this C# code, it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, I wonder why?

```
    ConcurrentStack<int> intsStack = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
    int[] myInts = new int[0];
    intsStack.PushRange(myInts);
```

The `Message` property of the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error:

> The startIndex argument must be greater than or equal to zero.
>
> Parameter name: startIndex

The array is empty but not `null`, I didn't expect any exception at all, just that nothing was added to the stack. Is this a reasonable exception or not?

Comment: what happens if you `MyInts[0] = 0;` BEFORE calling `PushRange` ?

Comment: Did this work with a different implementation of `Stack`?

Comment: @Yahia: That would give him an `IndexOutOfRangeException` as the array has zero capacity.

Answer (score 4):

**From an implementation perspective**, it's reasonable if you look at the definition of the [PushRange(T[], int, int) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381934.aspx):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: *startIndex* or *count* is negative. Or *startIndex* is greater than or equal to the length of items.

The length of your array is zero. Therefore, there is no possible valid value for *startIndex*.

**From a documentation perspective**, it's not reasonable, because the documentation of the [PushRange(T[]) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394954.aspx) does not mention the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: It's not reasonable, period.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to AddRange is an empty array, so you are trying to push zero items on to the stack. So it's a very reasonable exception.

EDIT: But you're right, it's a bad exception message. You can guess that it is because internally the overload PushRange(T[], Int32, Int32) is actually throwing the exception.

Comment: Yes, but why is it 'so bad' to push an empty array? You will not get an exception when you add an empty array to a list via AddRange().

Comment: @TTT clearly just some arbitrary decision made by a person who had no actual usage of PushRange in practice.

Answer (score 2):

If the array is empty, it has no index 0, which is what it is complaining about.

With a zero based index, 0 is the first index, pointing to the first item.  So it is actually complaining that there is nothing in the array.